# There are no open seats available for selected center - The Embassy of the Federal Republic of Germany, New Delhi

Tags: visas, germany, india, covid-19, vfs-global

When I am trying to book an appointment on VFS global, I am getting the following message, "There are no open seats available for the selected center - The Embassy of the Federal Republic of Germany, New Delhi".

I am from India, and I want to apply for a German national visa. Due to the ongoing Covid-19 Pandemic, VFS offices and the German embassy office are temporarily closed, but there is no information as to when are they going to open. I am not able to see any calendar or dates for available seats and there are only 3 months remaining for the University course to begin.

Is there any other way to book an appointment or something I am missing?

Comment: As the university is probably aware of the exceptional circumstances and difficulties, it's probably worth it to ask theit Student Office about your options. EU has closed it's borders for an unknown time, so they may already have some systematic solution for foreign students who got trapped outside. Or if not, making them aware doesn't hurt.

Answer (score 28):

The [website of the German embassy in India](https://india.diplo.de/) currently displays this notice:

> No visa queries are being addressed at the moment. Due to the ongoing pandemic, the German Embassy New Delhi is open for emergencies only. All visa related activities are on hold including decisions/issuing/extension of visas, long term national visas, Schengen visas and visa stamping. The Visa Section of the German missions as well as the offices of our service provider, VFS Global, remain closed until further notice.

In short, no visa applications can be made "until further notice".

This answer is unfortunate in your circumstances, but clear. You can't apply at this time, and there's no public information about when that will change. All you can do is keep checking the website for any updates.